# How to convert ImageSource to bool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

I have `Image` and `Button SaveToDisk`. So, when Image not loaded (ImageSource is null) - i need to block `SaveToDisk` button. And vice versa.

So, i deside to use converter. But it not works for me:

```
 public class SourceToEnableConverter:IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((ImageSource)value == null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:SourceToEnableConverter x:Key="SourceToEnableConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And WPF XAML image:

```
 <Image Name="imIcon" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,0,0,8"
                   >
                <Image.Source>
                    <Binding Path="ObjectViewModel.Image" >

                        <!--<Binding.TargetNullValue>
                            <Image Source="Empty.png"></Image>
                        </Binding.TargetNullValue>-->
                    </Binding>
                </Image.Source>                                                         
            </Image>
```

Button:

```
 <Button Name="btnSaveIcon" Click="btnSaveIcon_Click"
                    Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Margin="8,0,0,8"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Content="SaveAs"}"
                    Height="44" 
                    IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=imIcon,Path=Source,Converter={StaticResource SourceToEnableConverter}}"
                    />
```

And Output error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 23 : Cannot convert '<null>' from type '<null>' to  type 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource' for 'ru-RU' culture with default conversions; consider using Converter property of Binding. NotSupportedException:'System.NotSupportedException
```

Can you help me? May be i should use something else? Or, i use `IValueConverter` in wrong way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like null is not a valid value for ImageSource.
Try changing

```
if ((ImageSource)value == null) return false;
```

to

```
if (value == null) return false;
```

Comment: Even simpler: `return value != null;`

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `Command` instead. Use the `CanExecute` method to determine if the button is enabled, like so:

### XAML

```
    <Window x:Class="ImageDemo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageDemo"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <RoutedCommand x:Key="LoadImage"/>
        <RoutedCommand x:Key="UnloadImage"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource LoadImage}" CanExecute="LoadImage_CanExecute" Executed="LoadImage_Executed"/>
        <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource UnloadImage}" CanExecute="UnloadImage_CanExecute" Executed="UnloadImage_Executed"/>
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <DockPanel Margin="5">
        <Image x:Name="imgPlaceholder" Height="100" Width="100" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Button Content="Load Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Command="{StaticResource LoadImage}"/>
            <Button Content="Unload Image" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Command="{StaticResource UnloadImage}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

### Code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public BitmapImage bitmap;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        bitmap.BeginInit();
        bitmap.UriSource = new Uri("C:\\Temp\\the_ugly_baby.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
        bitmap.EndInit();
        imgPlaceholder.Source = null;

    }

    private void LoadImage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imgPlaceholder.Source = bitmap;
    }

    private void LoadImage_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = imgPlaceholder.Source == null ? true : false;
    }

    private void UnloadImage_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = imgPlaceholder.Source != null ? true : false;
    }

    private void UnloadImage_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imgPlaceholder.Source = null;
    }
}
```

If `CanExecute` is `true` then your button will be enabled. The really nice things about Commands is that you can reuse them on menus and pretty much any control while the button's Click event is only valid for buttons.

I would use a `DataContext` normally but to show the use of Commands I think this will do nicely.